# AmCharts reload after request fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, templates, amcharts

I have a Django template, that renders an AmChart chart. The chart is loaded by dataLoader, from an URL inside the Django (that returns the JSON with the data). If the link returns an error(ex.server is down), the chart freeze in the "Loading Data" part, and if a new request (ex. by modifying the form) is sent, and gets a correct response, the chart will still be frozen in the "Loading Data" part.

Is there a way for the chart to render again with the new data after these errors, without refreshing the whole page?

Known things:
The URL gives a correct json to the chart.
These happen when the link returns a status='(failed)'

template:

```
    {% extends "reporting_base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block container %}
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 800px; background-color: #FFFFFF;" ></div>
        </div>

        <div id="tableContainer"
             class="container-fluid"
             style="margin-top: 2%;"
             data-ng-app="videoconferenceRoomsUsage"
             ng-controller="videoconferenceRoomsUsageController">

            {% if campaign %}
            <div class="row form-inline well">
              <h3 id="reportName">{{ campaign }}<h3>

              {% if campaign.created_by == user %}
                <a data-url="{% url 'create_campaign' %}?campaign={{campaign.pk}}" id="saveChanges" class="btn btn-success" href="#">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>
                  {% trans 'Save changes' %}
                </a>

                <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createCampaignModal" id="editCampaign" class="btn btn-primary" href="#">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                  {% trans 'Edit campaign' %}
                </a>

                <a data-url="{% url 'remove_campaign' campaign.pk %}" data-redirect-url="{% url 'reporting_home' %}" id="deleteCampaign" class="btn btn-danger" href="#">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                  {% trans 'Delete' %}
                </a>
              {% endif %}

            </div>
            {% endif %}

            <form style="text-align: center" id="problemsEvolutionForm" class="form-inline well">
              <div class="form-group">
                  {{ form.frequency }}
              </div>

              <div style="display:inline-block" class="form-group">
                  {{ form.clients }}
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                  {{ form.time_in_advance }}
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                  {{ form.sites }}
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                  <label>
                      {{ form.ignore_weekends }}
                      {{ form.ignore_weekends.label }}
                  </label>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                  <label>
                      {{ form.ignore_test_calls }}
                      {{ form.ignore_test_calls.label }}
                  </label>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                {% if user.is_staff and not campaign %}
                  <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createCampaignModal" class="btn btn-primary" href="">{% trans 'Create campaign' %}</a>
                {% endif %}
              </div>
            </form>

            <div class="modal fade" id="createCampaignModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
              <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">
                      {% if campaign %}
                        {% trans 'Edit campaign' %}
                      {% else %}
                        {% trans 'Create campaign' %}
                      {% endif %}
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <form id="createCampaignForm" class="form form-horizontal" role="form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="id_name">{{ create_campaign_form.name.label }}</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-10">
                            {{ create_campaign_form.name }}
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="id_description">
                            {{ create_campaign_form.description.label }}
                          </label>
                          <div class="col-sm-10">
                            {{ create_campaign_form.description }}
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="id_public">
                              {{ create_campaign_form.public.label }}
                          </label>

                          <div class="col-sm-10">
                            {{ create_campaign_form.public }}
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="codename" value="videoconference-rooms-usage">
                    </form>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">{% trans 'Close' %}</button>
                    <button data-url="{% url 'create_campaign' %}{% if campaign %}?campaign={{campaign.pk}}{% endif %}" id="createCampaign" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">{% trans 'Save' %}</button>
                  </div>
                </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
              </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
            </div><!-- /.modal -->
            <table id="intervalDataTable" class="table table-responsive">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="text text-center">{% trans 'Interval' %}</th>
                  <th class="text text-center">{% trans 'Time (Hours)' %}</th>
                  <th class="text text-center">{% trans 'Quantity of reservations' %}</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="data in chartData">
                  {% verbatim %}
                  <td class="text text-center">
                    {[{ data.category }]}
                  </td>
                  <td class="text text-center">
                    {[{ formatHours(
                    data.dataContext.hours) 
                    }]}
                  </td>
                  <td class="text text-center">
                    {[{ data.dataContext.reservations }]}
                  </td>
                  {% endverbatim %}
                </tr>
              </tbody>

            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock container %}

{% block override_js %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "amcharts/amcharts.js" %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "amcharts/serial.js" %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "amcharts/plugins/dataloader/dataloader.min.js" %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static "vendor/bootstrap-select/js/bootstrap-select.min.js" %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static "vendor/bootstrap-select/js/i18n/defaults-es_CL.min.js" %}"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Array.prototype.removeValue = function(val) {
          for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            if (this[i] === val) {
                this.splice(i, 1);
                i--;
            }
          }
          return this;
        };

        $.ajaxSetup({ traditional: true });

        $(document).ready(
          function(){
              $('#problemsEvolutionForm select,#problemsEvolutionForm input').on(
                'change',
                function() {
                  var tableElement = document.getElementById("tableContainer");
                  var scope = angular.element(tableElement).scope();

                  scope.makeChart();
                  scope.$apply();
                }
              );

              var initialState = $("tableContainer").html()

              $("#saveChanges").click(function(){
                var saveChangesUrl = $(this).data('url');

                swal({
                  title: "{% trans 'Are you sure?' %}",
                  text: "{% trans 'Click OK to save' %}",
                  type: "info",
                  showCancelButton: true,
                  cancelButtonText: "{% trans 'Cancel' %}",
                  closeOnConfirm: false,
                  showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
                },
                function(){
                  var data = collectData();

                  $.post(
                    saveChangesUrl,
                    data,
                    function(result){
                      swal(
                        {
                          title: "{% trans 'Saved!' %}",
                          text: "{% trans 'Your campaign has been saved!' %}",
                          type: "success"
                        }
                      );
                    }
                  ).fail(function(){
                    swal({
                      title: "Error!",
                      text: "{% trans 'An unexpected error has happened, please try again in a couple of minutes. If the problem persists, contact support.' %}",
                      type: "error",
                      confirmButtonText: "OK"
                    });
                  });;
                });
              });

              $("#deleteCampaign").click(function(){
                var deleteCampaignUrl = $(this).data('url');
                var redirectUrl = $(this).data('redirect-url');

                swal({
                  title: "{% trans 'Are you sure?' %}",
                  text: "{% trans 'You will not be able to recover this campaign!' %}",
                  type: "warning",
                  showCancelButton: true,
                  cancelButtonText: "{% trans 'Cancel' %}",
                  confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                  confirmButtonText: "{% trans 'Delete' %}",
                  closeOnConfirm: false
                },
                function(){
                  $.post(
                    deleteCampaignUrl,
                    {},
                    function(response){
                      if(response == 'Deleted'){
                        function redirectToHome(){
                            window.location = redirectUrl;
                        }

                        setTimeout(redirectToHome, 5000);

                        swal(
                          {
                            title: "{% trans 'Deleted!' %}",
                            text: "{% trans 'Your campaign has been deleted!' %}",
                            type: "success"  
                          },
                          redirectToHome
                        );
                      }
                    }
                  ).fail(function(){
                    swal({
                      title: "Error!",
                      text: "{% trans 'An unexpected error has happened' %}",
                      type: "error",
                      confirmButtonText: "OK"
                    });
                  });
                });
              });

              $("#createCampaignForm input,#createCampaignForm textarea").addClass('form-control');

              function collectData(){
                var result = {};
                var campaignData = $("#createCampaignForm").serializeArray();
                var reportData = $("#problemsEvolutionForm").serializeArray();

                for (var i = 0; i < campaignData.length; i++){
                  result[campaignData[i]['name']] = campaignData[i]['value'];
                }

                for(var j=0; j<reportData.length; j++){
                  var key = reportData[j]['name'];

                  if(key === 'sites' || key === 'mcus' || key === 'clients'){
                    if(result[key] === undefined){
                      result[key] = [];
                    }

                    result[key].push(reportData[j]['value']);
                  }
                  else{
                    result[key] = reportData[j]['value'];
                  }
                }

                return result;
              }

              $("#createCampaign").on('click', function(){
                var data = collectData();
                var url = $(this).data('url');

                $.post(
                  url,
                  data,
                  function(result){
                    $('#createCampaignModal').modal('hide');

                    var reportName = $("#id_name").val();

                    if($("h3#reportName").length > 0){
                      $("h3#reportName").html(reportName);
                    }

                    swal(
                      {
                        title: "{% trans 'Saved!' %}",
                        text: "{% trans 'Your campaign has been saved!' %}",
                        type: "success"
                      }
                    );
                  }
                )
              });

              $("select").selectpicker(
                {
                  size: 15,
                  lang: 'en-us',
                  deselectAllText: "{% trans 'Deselect all' %}",
                  selectAllText: "{% trans 'Select all' %}",
                  noneSelectedText: "{% trans 'Nothing selected' %}"
                }
              );

              var hiddenSites = [];

              $("select#id_clients").on(
                'changed.bs.select',
                function(){
                  var clientIds = $(this).val();

                  if(clientIds === null){
                      clientIds = [];
                      for(var k=0; k<hiddenSites.length; k++){
                        $(hiddenSites[k]).appendTo("#id_sites");
                      }

                      hiddenSites = [];
                      $("#id_sites").selectpicker('refresh');

                      return;
                  }

                  for(var i=0; i<clientIds.length; i++){
                    var clientId = clientIds[i];
                    var selectedItem = $("select#id_clients>option[value=" + clientId + "]");
                    var clientName = selectedItem.text();

                    var openBracketIndex = clientName.indexOf('(');

                    if(openBracketIndex !== -1){
                      clientName = clientName.slice(openBracketIndex+1, -1)
                    }

                    if(clientName !== undefined){
                      var foundIndex = null;

                      for(var j=0; j<hiddenSites.length; j++){
                        var currentSiteName = hiddenSites[j];

                        if(currentSiteName.attr('label') === clientName){
                          foundIndex = j;

                          var optGroups = $("select#id_sites").find(">optgroup");

                          if(optGroups.length === 0){
                            $(hiddenSites[j]).appendTo("#id_sites");
                          }
                          else{
                            var lastOptItem = optGroups.last();
                            var lastOptName = lastOptItem.attr('label');

                            var firstOptItem = optGroups.first();
                            var firstOptName = firstOptItem.attr('label');

                            if(clientName > lastOptName){
                              $(hiddenSites[j]).appendTo("#id_sites");
                            }
                            else if(clientName < firstOptName){
                              $(hiddenSites[j]).prependTo("#id_sites");
                            }
                            else{
                              var spliceIndex = foundIndex;
                              foundIndex = null;

                              $.each(
                                optGroups,
                                function(i, optItem){
                                  var wrappedOptItem = $(optItem);
                                  if(wrappedOptItem.attr('label') > clientName){
                                    wrappedOptItem.before($(hiddenSites[j]));
                                    hiddenSites.splice(spliceIndex, 1);
                                    return false;
                                  }
                                }
                              );
                            }
                          }

                          break;
                        }
                      }

                      if(foundIndex !== null){
                        hiddenSites.splice(foundIndex, 1)
                      }
                    }
                  }

                  var deselectedItems = $("select#id_sites>optgroup");

                  for(var l=0; l<deselectedItems.length; l++){
                    var notSelectedClientItem = deselectedItems[l];
                    var notSelectedClientName = notSelectedClientItem.label;
                    var notSelectedClientId = $("select#id_clients>option:contains('" + notSelectedClientName + "')").val();

                    if(notSelectedClientId !== null){
                        var found = false;

                        for(var m=0; m<clientIds.length; m++){
                          if(clientIds[m] === notSelectedClientId){
                            found = true;
                            break;
                          }
                        }

                        if(!found){
                          hiddenSites.push($(notSelectedClientItem).remove());
                        }
                    }
                  }

                  $("#id_sites").selectpicker('refresh');
              });
          }
        );

        function handleDataUpdated(event){
            var tableElement = document.getElementById("tableContainer");
            var scope = angular.element(tableElement).scope();

            if(event.chart !== undefined && scope !== undefined)
            {
                var chartData = event.chart.chartData;
                var invertedChartData = [];

                for(var i=chartData.length - 1; i>=0; i--){
                  invertedChartData.push(chartData[i]);
                }

                scope.chartData = invertedChartData;
                scope.$apply();
            }
        }

      var app = angular.module(
        'videoconferenceRoomsUsage',
        []
      );

      app.config(
        function($interpolateProvider) {
          $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{');
          $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]}');
        }
      );

      app.controller(
        'videoconferenceRoomsUsageController',
        [
          '$scope',
          function($scope) {
            $scope.chartData = [];
            $scope.getHours = function(d){
                return (Math.round(d * 100 / 3600) / 100) + "h";
            };

            $scope.formatHours = function(d){
                return Math.round(d*100)/100 + "h"
            }

            $scope.getUrl = function(){
                var queryString = "?" + $("form").serialize();
                return "{% url 'new_reservations_json' %}" + queryString;
            };

            $scope.makeChart = function(){
                if($scope.chart !== undefined){
                    var chart = $scope.chart;
                    chart.dataLoader.url = $scope.getUrl();
                    chart.dataLoader.loadData();
                }
                else{
                    $scope.chart = AmCharts.makeChart(
                    "chartdiv",
                    {
                      "type": "serial",
                      "listeners": [
                          {
                            "event": "dataUpdated",
                            "method": handleDataUpdated
                          }
                        ],
                        "categoryField": "category",
                        "startDuration": 1,
                        "categoryAxis": {
                          "gridPosition": "start"
                        },
                        "trendLines": [],
                        "graphs": [
                          {
                            "color": "RGB(152,72,7)",
                            "colorField": "color",
                            "fillAlphas": 1,
                            "id": "Hours",
                            "labelText": "[[value]]",
                            "lineColor": "rgb(152,72,7)",
                            "lineColorField": "color",
                            "title": "{% trans 'Conference hours' %}",
                            "type": "column",
                            "valueAxis": "Hours-Axis",
                            "valueField": "hours"
                          },
                          {
                            "bulletBorderThickness": 0,
                            "color": "rgb(250, 120,15)",
                            "cursorBulletAlpha": 0,
                            "customBullet": "",
                            "fillColors": "rgb(250, 120,15)",
                            "id": "Room-Quantity",
                            "labelText": "[[value]]",
                            "lineColor": "rgb(250, 120,15)",
                            "title": "{% trans 'Quantity of reservations' %}",
                            "valueAxis": "Room-Quantity-Axis",
                            "valueField": "reservations"
                          }
                        ],
                        "legend": {
                            "enabled": true,
                            "useGraphSettings": true,      
                        },
                        "guides": [],
                        "export" : exportConfiguration,
                        "valueAxes": [
                          {
                            "id": "Hours-Axis",
                            "title": "{% trans 'Time (Hours)' %}",
                            "position": "right",
                          },
                          {
                            "id": "Room-Quantity-Axis",
                            "title": "{% trans 'Quantity of reservations' %}"
                          }
                        ],
                        "allLabels": [],
                        "balloon": {},
                        "titles": [
                          {
                            "id": "Room-Usage",
                            "size": 15,
                            "text": "{% trans 'New Reservations' %}"
                          }
                        ],
                        "dataLoader": {
                          "url": $scope.getUrl(),
                          "format": "json",
                        }
                    }
                    );
                }
            };

            $scope.makeChart();
          }
        ]
      );
    </script>
{% endblock %}

{% block extra_css %}
    <link href="{% static "vendor/bootstrap-select/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <style>
        #problemsEvolutionForm .form-group {
            margin-left: 20px;
        }

        #id_call_type, #id_videoconference_mode{
            list-style: none;
            text-align: left;
            padding-left: 10px;
            padding-top: 4px;
        }
    </style>
{% endblock extra_css %}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's odd. Try clearing & recreating the chart completely.

```
$scope.makeChart = function(){

  if($scope.chart !== undefined){

    // clear chart
    $scope.chart.clear();
    $scope.chart = undefined;

  }

  $scope.chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
    // ...
    "dataLoader": {
      "url": $scope.getUrl(),
      "format": "json"
    }
  });

}
```

Hope this helps!